# Is date created by dateByAddingTimeInterval depended on Device date time or clock time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I create a local notification to get fired after 24 hours for an event. I created the date time for the firing dates by using the function dateByAddingTimeInterval. But for testing purpose i changed the device date time something close to my firing date. However the local notificate did not get fired. Just wanted to know whether the FiringDate time for the local notification will depend on system date time or something else.

Thanks in advance

Philip

Comment: How are you validating the dates you are creating?

Comment: i am able to see the firing date in debug mode.its coming proper.

Comment: How though?  I am concerned that you are unaware that you are viewing the dates in GMT.